# What’s the difference between *.duckduckgo.com and duckduckgo.com?

Tags: security, duckduckgo, dns, ssl

What’s the difference between `*.duckduckgo.com` and `duckduckgo.com`? On the SSL certificate it shows the two at the bottom as valid DNS for DuckDuckGo. I understand the asterisk is a wildcard in code, but before a lot of domains I see the same thing. Can someone briefly answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

In computer networking, a wildcard certificate is a public key certificate which can be used with multiple sub-domains of a domain.

A single wildcard certificate for `https://*.example.com` will secure all these subdomains on the `https://*.example.com` domain:

`payment.example.com`      
                 `contact.example.com`      
                 `login-secure.example.com` 
                 `www.example.com`

Instead of getting separate certificates for subdomains, you can use a single certificate for all main domains and subdomains and reduce cost and complexity.

Source: [Wikipedia Wildcard certificate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate)